# Data migration tool : How can i use time zone handler for order purchase time for magento 1 server on IST timezone

Tags: migration, data-migration, data-migration-tool

I use the tool for migrate my data from my **1.9.2.4** to magento2.2.2

It works except a problem with date of purchase.

There is a difference of 5:30 hours, however the time zone on M1 Server is IST (Indian Standard Time)

I have configured **map.xml**

```
        <transform>
            <field>sales_order.created_at</field>
            <handler class="\Migration\Handler\Timezone">
                <param name="offset" value="+5:30"/> 
            </handler>
        </transform>
```

It is not working

Comment: the same issue happened with me. Did you find solution

Comment: @user3906244 can u please suggest me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291709/magento-2-data-migration-time-difference

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you configured that in **vendor/magento/data-migration-tool-etc/`<FROM-TO>`/map-sales.xml**?  If so, also make sure to update your **vendor/magento/data-migration-tool-etc/`<FROM-TO>`/`<VERSION>`/config.xml** to point to the new file instead of the original distributed file.  So as an example, change...

```
<sales_order_map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/map-sales.xml.dist</sales_order_map_file>
```

to

```
<sales_order_map_file>etc/commerce-to-commerce/map-sales.xml</sales_order_map_file>
```